# How many processes should my daemon have?

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, supervisord, laravel-forge, daemons

I have an ubuntu server with a nuxt.js app (Vue.js).

On deploy I build the app and I have a daemon which runs and which I kill at the end of the deployment (so it restarts basically).

My question is: How many processes should I have for the daemon and what is their purpose?

[Screenshot from Laravel forge daemon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuJW8.png)